# Can't push selected items in array - Angular material mat select multiple

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, angular-material

Could someone help me to identify where im doing wrong when pushing data to empty array?

So, Am trying to push only selected values (i.e only checked true). but i cant go inside the loop

condition i had now

```
const vals = [];
    if (e && e.source.selected.length > 0) {
      console.log('selected values', e.source.selected);
      const sel = e.source.selected;
      sel.forEach((e: any) => {
        if (sel._selected) {
          vals.push(e);
          console.log('EE', e);
        }
      });
    }
```

[demo blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fmgz12?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-custom-trigger-example.ts)

**expected:**

```
selectedList : [
{ id: '0' }, { id: '1' }, { id: '2' }
]
```

**Purpose:**

trying to bind same data in edit mode in form

Comment: *"Can't push..."*: not sure what that means. You get an error? The code hangs? The result is a different array than expected? Did you debug the code? Does it execute the all the lines? If `vals` was not populated as expected, then how did you come to that conclusion? ...etc.

Comment: @trincot yes i debugged that. i was able to execute till if condition and can entire dom printed in console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need your function at all. Remove it completely and instead do

```
console.log(e.source.value);
```

It automatically contains all selected values !

Each time you make an update the array will be updated as well to contain only the selected values.

If you want to transform it

> expected:
>
> selectedList : [ { id: '0' }, { id: '1' }, { id: '2' } ]

then just do

```
let selectedList = e.source.value.map((elem: number) => ({ id: elem }));
console.log(selectedList);
```

Comment: yeah @Panagiotis Bougioukos i tried that intiallay. but i want to push only selected items to get ` selectedList : [{ id: '0' }, { id: '1' }, { id: '2' }]` thats where im got stuck

Comment: getting `undefined` when i print `let selectedList = e.source.value.map( (element: any )=> {id: element} );
      console.log('final', selectedList)` . seems its not iterating dom `value : ['0']`

Comment: @Mr.Learner updated my answer. It works on stackblitz please check, upvote and accept answer :D

Comment: copy exactly my code because there is an extra set of `( )` to be able to work ;)

Comment: Sorry.. my mistake.  `id: element.value` fixes the issue . so accepted your lead :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `if` condition is wrong, the corrected version should be as below:

```
const vals = [];
if (e && e.source.selected.length > 0) {
  console.log('selected values', e.source.selected);
  const sel = e.source.selected;
  sel.forEach((e: any) => {
    if (e.selected) {
      vals.push({"id": e.value});
      console.log('EE', {"id": e.value});
    }
  });
}
```

Unless you are trying something different. You could try putting a console statement before your `if` condition inside loop to check what was going wrong.

Comment: seems still cant get expected output as mentioned above. @Rahul.R

Comment: e is full dom object, you need to create a new object with just id, and push the same one.

Comment: Yes the problem is there only, dont know how to get that value. but that DOM has `value` property with `['1']`

Comment: Updated the answer, just check if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
onSelectingToppings(e: any) {

const vals:any[] = [];
if (e && e.source.selected.length > 0) {
  // console.log('selected values', e.source.selected);
  const sel = e.source.selected;
  sel.forEach((item: any) => {
    if (item._selected) {
      vals.push(item);
    }
  });
  console.log(vals.length)
}
}
```

Comment: its behaving same like mine only @rohan .. but trying to achieve to get selected items like `selectedList : [
{ id: '0' }, { id: '1' }, { id: '2' }
]`

Answer (score 0):

Add optional chaining to prevent error when no value selected/page initialized. Then `sel` holds the the array of selected values. See below for updated code

```
    if (e && e.source?.selected?.length > 0) {
      console.log('selected values', e);
      const sel = e.source.selected;
      sel?.value?.forEach((e: any) => {
          vals.push(e);
          console.log('EE', e);
    
      });
    }
```